# Why does $\left(x \cdot \tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)-1\right)^{-1}$ asymptotically approach $3x^2 - 6/5$?

Tags: limits, trigonometry

I noticed that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)*x = 1$ and I was wondering how fast it approaches $1$. I looked at $\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)*x-1}$ and found that this grows slower than $x^3$, so to find what polynomial degree it grows as fast as, I plugged it into $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(f\left(x\right)\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\ln\left(\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)*x-1}\right)}{\ln\left(x\right)}=2$ to find that it grows around as fast as $x^2$. Then I tried plugging $\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)*x-1\right)*x^2$ into Wolfram|Alpha and it produced $1/3$. It was not able to provide any steps. How is this limit calculated? Using this, the next question I come upon is how $\lim_{x\to\infty}3x^2-\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)*x-1} = 6/5$ is calculated. Why does $\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)*x-1\right)^{-1}$ asymptotically approach $3x^2 - 6/5$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have that by Taylor's series

$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac1x+\frac1{3x^3}+o\left(\frac1{x^3}\right)$$

and therefore

$$\left(\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot x-1\right)\cdot x^2=\left(1+\frac1{3x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)-1\right)\cdot x^2=\frac 13+o(1) \to \frac 13$$

and since

$$\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=\frac1x+\frac1{3x^3}+\frac2{15x^5}+o\left(\frac1{x^5}\right)$$

$$\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot x-1}=\left(\frac1{3x^2}+\frac2{15x^4}+o\left(\frac1{x^4}\right)\right)^{-1}=$$

$$=3x^2\left(1+\frac2{5x^2}+o\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)^{-1}=3x^2-\frac6{5}+o\left(1\right)$$

then

$$3x^2-\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\cdot x-1}=\frac65+o(1) \to \frac65$$

Comment: To get $\frac 65$ (if it is correct) one will also need the fifth order term in Taylor for tan.

Comment: @YuDing Yes of course! I add that also.

Comment: Neat, it seems I've simply stumbled upon the series expansion. Wolfram|Alpha is able to show more of the terms [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=series+%28x*tan%281%2Fx%29-1%29%5E-1)

Comment: @Waffle The trick is to use Taylor's series for $\tan \frac1x$ and then the binomial series.